# Drag:end event propname to find the lat lng

Tags: here-api

To get the lat lng of the pin drag:end event we used to have this object:

```
Ig: Q {f: {…}, g: cf, ud: false, Ua: undefined, S: re, …}
 J: undefined 
N: true P: 3 
S: re {src: Kn, a: {…}, b: 0} 
Ua: undefined 
X: jh {a: -9007199254740901, b: -9007199254740945, f: -9007199254740901} 
b: lg {lat: 50.85869033522973, lng: 5.388701859595967}
draggable: true 
fa: ak {0: -50.85869033522973, 1: 5.388701859595967, id: 87, node: Ag, c: Kn}
```

At some point this changed to:

```
Ig: Q {f: {…}, g: cf, ud: false, Ua: undefined, S: re, …}
 J: undefined 
N: true P: 3 
S: re {src: Kn, a: {…}, b: 0} 
Ua: undefined 
X: jh {a: -9007199254740901, b: -9007199254740945, f: -9007199254740901} 
a: lg {lat: 50.85869033522973, lng: 5.388701859595967}
draggable: true 
fa: ak {0: -50.85869033522973, 1: 5.388701859595967, id: 87, node: Ag, c: Kn}
```

Can someone explain this why and how to prevent the propname change?

```
map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target;
        if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
            behavior.enable();
            setLocationCoordFields(target.a)
            map.setCenter(target.a);
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: can you add command which produced this object?

Comment: @Tomas I have added the eventlistener on the drag:end

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get Marker's coordinate using 'a' or 'b' property name - this way is incorrect because those names is obfuscated names and they are utilized only internally by API itself.

Please use only name of methods/properties which specified in documentation of JS API(https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.12/api_reference/index.html) or Javascript lang.

Regarding documentation on https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.12/api_reference/H.map.Marker.html#getGeometry in your case the code should be:

```
setLocationCoordFields(target.getGeometry());
map.setCenter(target.getGeometry());
```

Keep in mind that internal variable/property/method name will be chanded by every new release version of JS API.